# Reading uint Array properties inside WMI in Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, wmi

I am having trouble reading uint ARRAYS properties from WMI objects.  I can read and process STRING properties from WMI objects.

This is what I have tried:

```
VARIANT vtProp; 
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"VendorSpecific", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);// Uint8
```

Comment: VARIANT vtProp;
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"VendorSpecific", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);// Uint8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VARIANT vtProp;
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"VendorSpecific", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);// Uint8

long lUpper = 0;
long lLower = 0;
hr = SafeArrayGetUBound(V_ARRAY(&vtProp),1,&lUpper);
hr = SafeArrayGetLBound(V_ARRAY(&vtProp),1,&lLower);
long lNumOfElems = lUpper-lLower+5;
BYTE HUGEP *plongArray;
BYTE b;
hr=SafeArrayAccessData(V_ARRAY(&vtProp), (void**)&plongArray);
b = plongArray[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you get the first element of the safe array.

```
SAFEARRAY* safearray = vtProp.parray;
CComBSTR str;
LONG i = 0;
SafeArrayGetElement(safearray, &i, &str);
```

UPDATE: A more general solution:

```
SAFEARRAY* safearray = vtProp.parray;
VARTYPE vType;
SafeArrayGetVartype(safearray, &vType);
long bound = safearray ->rgsabound[0].cElements;
for(long i = 0; i < bound; ++i)
{
   VARIANT value;
   SafeArrayGetElement(safearray, &i, &value);

   switch(vType)
   {
      case VT_BSTR: 
         // use value.bstrVal
         break;
      case VT_UI8:
         // use value.ullVal
         break;
   }
}
```